# Certificate for <jcenter.bintray.com> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I am clone a project from GitHub in Android Studio. When i open the project this error is shown 
Error: **Certificate for  doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [*.socialdrip.me, socialdrip.me]**
I can not find the problem and the file where the problem exist.

I can change the classpath from **Gradle Build file**. I also change the dependencies from **gradle app file**.

I have to run the project but there is a error in building gradle. and this error is shown.
**Error: Certificate for  doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [*.socialdrip.me, socialdrip.me]**

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same exact problem.  I cleared my cache and restarted the IDE.

File > Invalidate Caches/Restart > Invalidate and Restart

Comment: This did not solve the problem for me